# CNN does not perform well on simple image recognition problem of cats and dogs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a CNN in order to classify images of cats and dogs. After reading several examples on the internet I have come up with the following solution.The imports are:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2
import os
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.regularizers import l2
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

My CNN is the following:

```
model = Sequential()
inputShape = (height, width, depth)
# if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
  inputShape = (depth, height, width)

model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), input_shape = inputShape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(224*224*3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

where height and width equal to 224 and depth equals to 3 since I have RGB images. To read the images I use the following code. The directory is test_animals/cats/ and test_animals/dogs for cats and dogs respectively, where 1000 jpg images per label are located.

```
data = []
labels = []
# grab the image paths and randomly shuffle them
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images('test_animals')))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (img_width, img_height))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)
    # extract the class label from the image path and update the
    # labels list
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    label = 1 if label == "dogs" else 0
    labels.append(label)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
```

Then, I try to perform 10-fold cross validation by doing the following:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
current_fold = 1
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):
    print(f'[INFO] Current fold: {current_fold}')
    trainX, testX = data[train_index], data[test_index]
    trainY, testY = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]
    # Reserve 20% of the samples for validation
    num_val_samples = 0 - int(len(trainX)*0.2)
    x_val = trainX[num_val_samples:]
    y_val = trainY[num_val_samples:]
    trainX = trainX[:num_val_samples]
    trainY = trainY[:num_val_samples]
    # convert the labels from integers to vectors
    trainY = to_categorical(trainY, num_classes=2)
    y_val = to_categorical(y_val, num_classes=2)
    aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")
    model = LeNet.build(width=img_width, height=img_height, depth=3, num_classes=2)
    opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])
    H = model.fit(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),validation_data=(x_val, y_val), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
    y_pred = model.predict(testX, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
    y_pred_bool = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    print(classification_report(testY, y_pred_bool))
    current_fold += 1
```

The parameters of the experiment are currently:

```
EPOCHS = 50
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 10
img_width = 224
img_height = 224
num_classes = 2
```

The problem with my solution is that it always achieves an accuracy ~50% approximately. No matter the size of the epochs (I tried 10,25,50,100), the accuracy and the loss remain the same or sometimes drop as the epochs proceed. In addition, I have experimented with adding/dropping layers/maxpooling/conv2D, yet the result remains the same. When I increase the samples to 5000 per label, the accuracy gets even lower. Am I doing something wrong? Is there an explanation about it? What can I do to improve the accuracy of my model?

Here`s the link to the dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1baqbZar9ceYQidD_LaIFvoDWlB1QcyYA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you're going to use softmax activation in the output, you should use categorical (not binary) cross-entropy as loss function.

Comment: The result does not change. The result does not change even if I use sigmoid instead of softmax

Answer (score 0):

i think,

since you are using softmax activation, the loss should be the 'categorical_crossentropy'
try this

yesterday i worked on data set where i have to categorize images, i also augmented the data with rotation, but it seems that accuracy without augmenting data is quiet higher than accuracy after augmentation

i don't know what mistake i have done, but it happened

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment below my question, the same thing happens when I use categorical_crossentropy. Also, I saw somewhere in the Internet that when we have binary classification, it is best if we use binary crossentropy.

Comment: can you please provide me data set link....? i can also try....

Comment: I updated the question to include a link to the dataset. Look at the end of the question, you can find it there.